# Wildcard has no effect in IIS7 URL rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a webapp that on my local machine runs as the root url, however on the server it runs in new virtual directory of another website.

The problem I have is that all the images have been written like so;

```
<img src="/Images/image.jpg" .../>
```

However when I upload the webapp to the server the image needs to be like this

```
<img src="/myApp/Images/image.jpg .../>
```

So I thought I would use the rewrite module to change the image path and save myself some time.  Using IIS7 I have the following for the pattern;

```
*/Images/*
```

and this for the actions rewrite property

```
http://example.com/myApp/Images/{R:2}
```

However it doesn't work - this image is still showing as not found. Would someone point out my mistake?

Comment: I have the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

The pattern ought to be a regular expression, try match as

```
  ^.*?/Images/(.*)
```

and the rewrite url as

```
 /myApp/Images/{R:1}
```

Note this needs to be in the web.config for the site not the application.

Comment: Still not working, my config file looks like this

<rules>
<rule name="Redirect Images" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="false">
 <match url="^.*?/Images/(.*)" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/myApp/Images/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>

Comment: You've added this to the sites web.config right?  It won't work if you place in your application web.config.

Comment: Yeah, the ambiguity remains, which web.config? There are more than one at work here, the site's or the application's?